Android - login with Google button and Backup to Google Drive
In my android app I have a Google login button - when the users click on it, he logs in to Google accound and then can backup database to Google Drive. This works fine, but now the GoogleSignIn is deprecated.
After the user clicks on the button, I check if is already signed or not:
     if(!isSignedIn()) {
            requestSignIn();}
    
    private boolean isSignedIn() {
        return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null && GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
    }

 private void requestSignIn() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
                .build();

        GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);

        Intent signInIntent = client.getSignInIntent();
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
    }

   final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    handleSignInInent(result.getData());
                } else {
                    showMsgSnack(getString(R.string.nologin));
                }
            });

    private void handleSignInInent(Intent data) {
        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(googleSignInAccount -> {
                    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.
                            usingOAuth2(BackupActivity.this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));
etc...

As Google suggest to use Credential manager, all GoogleSignIn stuff are deprecated.
I tried to follow the documentation, but no success:
GetCredentialRequest request = new GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
  .addGetCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
  .build();

// Launch sign in flow and do getCredential Request to retrieve the credentials
credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(
  requireActivity(),
  request,
  cancellationSignal,
  <executor>,
  new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(GetCredentialResponse result) {
      handleSignIn(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(GetCredentialException e) {
      handleFailure(e);
    }
  }
);

public void handleSignIn(GetCredentialResponse result) {
  // Handle the successfully returned credential.
  Credential credential = result.getCredential();

  if (credential instanceof PublicKeyCredential) {
    String responseJson = ((PublicKeyCredential) credential).getAuthenticationResponseJson();
    // Share responseJson i.e. a GetCredentialResponse on your server to validate and authenticate
  } else if (credential instanceof PasswordCredential) {
    String username = ((PasswordCredential) credential).getId();
    String password = ((PasswordCredential) credential).getPassword();
    // Use id and password to send to your server to validate and authenticate
  } else if (credential instanceof CustomCredential) {
    if (GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL.equals(credential.getType())) {
      try {
        // Use googleIdTokenCredential and extract id to validate and
        // authenticate on your server
        GoogleIdTokenCredential googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(((CustomCredential) credential).getData());
      } catch (GoogleIdTokenParsingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Received an invalid Google ID token response", e);
      }
    } else {
      // Catch any unrecognized custom credential type here.
      Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential");
    }
  } else {
    // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
    Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential");
  }
}

It says GetCredentialRequest.Builder() Expected 1 arguments but found 0, also Cannot resolve symbol 'credentialManager',  and much more ...
And the main thing is, this is only for API>=34, I really don't want to keep my old code and credential manager as well only for API 34 and up.
And another issue is, how to check if the user is signed in already?
Can somebody help with a working code with backwards compatibility?

It seems to me that you're not using the Jetpack library and instead, are using the framework APIs directly. You should switch to the Jetpack library (androidx) that will provide the Builder class with no argument and also provides backward compatible APIs for your app.
I don't know how the sign-in is triggered in your app; if you have a button that says 'Sign-in with Google' that a user has to click on, then it is recommended to use a different type of options that you can build and pass to the same API; instead of building a request of type GetGoogelIdOptions, build one of the type GetSignInWithGoogleOptions (the rest would be the same), see also this.
Keep in mind that the Credential Manager library only provides "authentication" for your app. You had mentioned that you'd also need access to the user's Drive. For that, you need to use the separate "authorization" apis that are part of the Google Identity Services, see this developer documentation for details. If you run into issues with that, please post a separate question with details and I will try to help you out with that.

Thank you very much, yes, in my app, if the user is not logged in to Google, then I am showing a log in button, otherwise another screen is showing where user can backup data to Drive. I will try according your answer. However, to show the login button or not I need to check if the user is logged in. But I can't do it anymore with GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount as it is deprecated.

Here is my suggestion: keep the Sign-in with Google button as is. In addition, to make it smooth for your users, create a new call to Credential Manager to sign the user in, but use the GetGoogleIdOption for your request. There, use setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true) and setAutoSelectEnabled(true) and call the API as soon as user opens the app.  The net effect is the following: if a user had previously signed in to your app using one of the Google accounts on the device, they will automatically be signed-in again and you will receive an ID Token as usual to validate (continued ...)

(...continued) If, however, that was not the case, you will get a response that there was no such credential and that is a clue to you that you don't have a signed-in user yet. Then you can call the same API but this time with setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false); this results in showing a bottomsheet with all the available accounts for user to select one to sign in (or sign-up) to your app. If, for some reason, user cancels the bottomsheet, then you have the Sign-in with Google button there on the page if they want to sign in. This is the recommended flow for such cases.

I actually need to log in the user only in one activity, not for my whole app - only for Google drive Backup. So after the user logs in to Google, he will see the option to backup data to Google drive. Otherwise he will see Sign in button, but only in that activity. I posted my latest code in a new thread - now after clicking the button the user can select the account, but there is some issue with cancellation. Can you please check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78431888/android-use-new-getsigninwithgoogleoption-for-sign-in-with-google-button
