Android - GetSignInWithGoogleOption for Sign in to Google Drive - GoogleIdTokenCredential cannot be cast to HttpRequestInitializer
I want to achieve a simple Google sign in with google button and backup data to Google Drive. As the old GoogleSignIn is deprecated.

How to check, if user is logged in to Google or not - I need to show the Google Sign in button when not logged in and another view, when already logged ?
How to log in with the new way - GetSignInWithGoogleOption

I tried:
//here I don't know how to check if user is logged as this method is deprecated (GoogleSignIn)

    if (!isSignedIn()) {
        relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        signInWithGoogle();
    }

private boolean isSignedIn() {
    return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null && GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
}

Then I tried the new login:
//not sure why I need serverclientID from Webapp, if I don't have any web app.
 private void signInWithGoogle() {
        GetSignInWithGoogleOption googleIdOption = new GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder("serverclientID")
                .build();

        GetCredentialRequest request = new GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                .build();

        CredentialManager credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this);

        credentialManager.getCredentialAsync(
                this,
                request,
                new CancellationSignal(),
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                new CredentialManagerCallback<GetCredentialResponse, GetCredentialException>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(GetCredentialResponse result) {
                        Credential credential = result.getCredential();

                             Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder(
                                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                                     new GsonFactory(),
                                     (HttpRequestInitializer) credential)
                                .setApplicationName("MYAPP")
                                .build();

                        driveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);

                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.logscreen);
                        RelativeLayout relativeLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.logmenu);
                        relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(GetCredentialException e) {
                        // Handle error
                    }
                });
                    }

This code is almost working - i mean after clicking on Sign in button it shows the Google account, but after I select my account, I still see the Google Sign in button and nothing happens
It ends on onError with: GoogleIdTokenCredential cannot be cast to com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer
after I select my account.

What is the main reason that you want to sign the user in? Isn't it the case that you just want the ability to save into the user's drive? The reason I am asking is that you  can gain access to user's drive through Authorization APIs without signing the user in first.

I had it that way for years - user logs in in Google and then he had access to upload/download file from Google drive. Because to access Google drive you need to log in to Google account and I must enable to user also to logout and revoke access.

The credential that you get back in the onResult is not of the type HttpRequestInitializer, hence you get a cast exception when you do (HttpRequestInitializer) credential. Remember that the Credential Manager APIs are just there to help you with Authentication; you need to call the Authorization APIs directly to gain access to user's Drive folder. In fact, if that is all you want, there is no need to sign the user in first (see this post for example).

so this is something new for me, that I don't need to log in the user to Google account prior to work to Google Drive. I think the Authorization API will do everything? Log in, Log out or revoke access to Google Drive? Can you please help a little how to go with the Authorization in java only for Google drive, but with the new way, without GoogleSignIn?

If user is not signed in, user will see a list of accounts in an account picker UI and then they can select the account and give their consent. The result you get doesn't have the google account information (like gmail, profile image, ..) but it has an obfuscated ID, in addition to the tokens or codes they had asked for and were granted by the user. I suggest you follow the documentation and play with that to see how it works: https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android

I see. I tried that code from google doc, but can't connect it to my existing code and google has there deprecated startIntentSenderForResult so it is not up to date

Even though that piece of launching the pending intent and getting the result is deprecated, it still works; we will update the docs to use ActivityResultCallback and such but that wouldn't make any behavioral change in your case. You need to provide more information if something is not working on your side.

I want to avoid deprecated code. Even my old code with GoogleSignIn works, but is deprecated, that's why I want to replace it. But currently I have a problem with credential in Drive googleDriveService = new Drive.Builder. When using the code from your link, after access is granted to Google Drive, I should call e.g. saveToDriveAppFolder(authorizationResult); But in Drive builder still a HttpRequestInitializer is needed, but authorizationResult isn't.

Previously for Drive builder I used: GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.
usingOAuth2(BackupActivity.this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

From AuthorizationResult, you can get an AccessToken. Then you can create a GoogleCredential: GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential(); googleCredential.setAccessToken(accessToken). Then read https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java to see how you can use Drive apis to accomplish what you need; note that it is a different Drive than you had been using.

Thank you very much for your help sir! Finally it is working with credential.setAccessToken(data.getAccessToken()); Now I am trying to figure out, how to disconnect user (log out or revoke access) from Google Drive, I found only clearCredentialState(), but not sure how and where should I call or is there any other solution as before I had it via client.revokeAccess()

Hi @Darksymphony did you use https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java ? com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential seems to be deprecated too

I don't see GoogleCredential is deprecated.. GoogleSignIn is deprecated.

It is deprecated at  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/main/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.java  Not sure if we ar eusing same package. which one are you using?

yes I am using com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential but in Android Studio it doesn't complain anything about deprecation. How do you connect to Google drive then?

Same way you do. I have just discovered   GoogleSignInClient was deprecated and been looking around. As usual, Google's samples does not go in to details. Found your first post and then this one.  val credential = GoogleCredential()                 credential.setAccessToken(accessToken) works but com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential is depraceted. I am using https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup#google-api-client-android

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
